# Proof that $\frac{x}{\sqrt y}+\frac{y}{\sqrt z}+\frac{z}{\sqrt x} \geq 3$ for $x+y+z=3$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $x+y+z=3$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are sides of a triangle, prove that $$\frac{x}{\sqrt y}+\frac{y}{\sqrt z}+\frac{z}{\sqrt x} \geq 3$$

We have $0< x,y,z<\frac{3}{2}$ from the triangle inequality.

Here's my attempt:

Multiply both sides by $\sqrt {xyz}$:
$$x \sqrt{xz}+y \sqrt{xy}+z \sqrt{xz} \geq3 \sqrt{xyz}$$
I am stuck here because if I use AM-GM on the left side it wouldn't work. I also tried to square both sides but it didn't help.

Comment: Since $x,y,z$ are sides of a triangle, you also have that $x+y > z, y + z > x, $ and $ z+ x > y.$ Not sure if these are helpful, but they *might* be...

Comment: Well if $x > \frac{3}{2}$, then $y + z < \frac{3}{2}$ which fails to satisfy the triangle inequality. So $0 < x,y,z < \frac{3}{2}$, but I agree that this condition isn't strict enough.

Comment: I know it's not an exact duplicate so feel free to not close the question.

Comment: @TobyMak Yes thanks, I didn't saw that question

Comment: @liszt16 I found it using [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/). [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) isn't working now.

Comment: Shoot, that's unfortunate since the question has now been closed by Community.